# Flexbox - make elements shrink in height when resizing the window

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So, I'm working on a to-do list that is part of a dashboard. I'm using display: flex because I'd like to add more sections and I need to easily make them shrink and break based on the browser's width.
However, I can't find the solution with the browser's height. Similarly, I want to make the elements fit and shrink correctly; I don't want scrollbars. (unless the height is way too small and the page becomes unusable but I think that can be done with media queries)
The content technically fits but when I add too many tasks into the list, this happens when the window's height is smaller than the normal:
[image: Window Resizing]

If the tasks are two-three - everything is fine. But once I add a lot - this is what happens.

My code

```css
#workspace {
  font-family: Jost;
  background: rgb(246, 246, 246);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: left;
  align-items: baseline;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#workspace #reminders h1 {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 28pt;
  margin-top: 28px;
  margin-left: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 22px;
}

#workspace #reminders .task {
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0px 0px 12px;
  width: 96.5%;
  min-width: 300px;
  padding: 12px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-left: 8px;
}

#workspace #reminders {
  margin-left: 28px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  flex: 0 0 800px;
  margin-top: 44px;
}

#workspace #reminders #scrolltask {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  scrollbar-width: thin;
  min-height: 0px;
  max-height: 682px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  padding-right: 18px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section id="workspace">
  <div id="reminders">
    <h1>Tasks</h1>
    <div id="scrolltask">
      <div class="task">
        <div class="options">
          <div class="finish">
            <label class="check">
                <input type="checkbox" class="checkTask"/>
                <div class="box"></div>
             </label>
          </div>
          <div class="change">
            <button class="editButton">Edit</button>
            <button>Delete</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <h2 class="taskdesc">Task Example</h2>
        <h3 class="person">Task Author</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    ...
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Maybe flex-wrap is better?

Comment: Where am I supposed to apply flex-wrap?

Answer (score 1):

You should use flex-wrap instead. More about [it](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap)